# Can Orika map primitive to Object?

Tags: java, orika

I have CustomConverter like this:

```
public class IdToBoConverter extends CustomConverter<Long, AbstractBo> {

    @Override
    public AbstractBoconvert(Long id, Type<? extends AbstractBo> type, MappingContext mappingContext) {
        return serviceRepository.getServiceInstance(type.getName()).load(id);
    }
}

// Registered globally as:
converterFactory.registerConverter("idToUjoConverter", idToUjoConverter);
```

It works perfectly with Long class, but it doesn't work with long primitive type. Can Orika handle it somehow? 
Coverter is not invoked and mapping throws exception "Encountered mapping of primitive to object".

I'm trying to convert from originally Kotlin data class in Java program:

```
data class Book(
    val library: Long,     // -> converted to java long
    val department: Long?  // -> converter to java.lang.Long
)
```

But Kotlin converts non-null Long valus to long.

Using java.lang.Long in Kotlin class works, but causes probles elsewhere.

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: Simlified: 
    [ERROR] Caused by: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: While attempting the following mapping:
    [ERROR] sourceType = CheckRequestRest
    [ERROR] sourceProperty = user(long)
    [ERROR] destinationType = CheckRequest
    [ERROR] destinationProperty = user(User)
    [ERROR] Error occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: empty code returned for spec ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.specification.Convert@12f104e9, sourceProperty = ((long)source.getUser()), destinationProperty = ((cz.effectiva.tritius.server.ujo.bo.User)destination.getUser())

Comment: MartinMahr how did you resolve this issue ? did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: I use "java.lang.Long" java type for required properties instead of kotlin's" Long". 

    data class Book{
        val id: java.lang.Long
    }